# How to display all the added files on a new line by using style

Tags: mercurial, logging, filenames, dvcs

I am able to display the modified files for a changeset on newlines by using the following style with hg log command.

```
changeset = "{files}"
file = "{file}\n"
```

But how to display the added files for a changeset on newlines? I have tried the following styles

1. Newline after `{file}`:

   ```
   changeset = "{file_adds}"
   file = "{file}\n"
   ```
2. Newline after `{file_add}`:

   ```
   changeset = "{file_adds}"
   file = "{file_add}\n"
   ```
3. Newline after `{file+}`:

   ```
   changeset = "{file_adds}"
   file = "{file+}\n"
   ```

Neither style works.

Answer (score 1):

Use a style with

```
changeset = "{file_adds}"
file_add = "{file_add}\n"
```

to get a newline-separated list of added file names from `hg log -v`.

(Yes, the template language is pretty horible and mostly undocumented.)